# Android CountDownTimer scoping

Tags: java, android, countdown

Can anyone tell me if this is a safe thing to do? I run a countdown timer (CountDownTimer) and when the timer reaches zero it must start again, counting down for, for example, a longer time. To do this I call

```
timer = new TableCount(nextTime * 1000, 100);
```

within the onFinish() method.

It runs without problems, but I'm concerned it may cause a memory leak. Should I rather have the timer fire some kind of notification that it is done? Here are the important bits from the activity code:

```
public class TableActivity extends Activity {
    TableCount timer; // the count down timer
    protected int nextTime;
    ...
    // somewhere I call this - user clicked the "start" button
    timer = new TableCount(nextTime * 1000, 100);
    nextTime += 100; // for example
    ...
    public class TableCount extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public void onFinish() {
            ... // check if number of iterations has been reached, else:
            // start counting down from the next value
            timer = new TableCount(nextTime * 1000, 100);
            nextTime += 100; // for example
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not leak memory since you are simply changing the reference of your single declaration of TableCount to a new timer which implicitly dereferences the previous object.

Even if you did something bizarre like creating a new timer each run and adding it to an array (for example) you would still not leak.  You might eventually run out of memory but that's not the same as leaking since when the activity is finished(), and assuming that you are not holding a static reference somewhere else, then the memory is freed and eligible for garbage collection.

However, why not just reuse the existing timer and use schedule() to run it again?

Comment: Thanks - I do a max of 8 iterations, so I think that memory usage is safe. By the way, CountDownTimer doesn't seem to have a schedule() method - it seems that it isn't too easy to reset the countdowntimer

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking Timer, not CountdownTimer.  In that case, what you're doing is fine.  In fact, you are not even adding to the memory used.  My point about the loop was that it would only use increasing memory if you somehow kept a hold of the previous instance of the timer, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

do not need to initialize timer again....
try this...

```
   int temp=nexttime;
   public class TableCount extends CountDownTimer
   {
       public void onFinish() {
       nexttime=temp;
       timer.start();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, calling timer.start() just starts from the original time again and not from nexttime

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ServiceCount extends CountDownTimer
{
    public ServiceCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
             count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 1 minute
             count.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        Log.d("timer", "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}

ServiceCount count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 1 minute
count.start();
```

Comment: You can change time in onFinish() i.e. `count = new ServiceCount((long) (2 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 2 minutes`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but your example is exactly the same as the one in the question. The question is whether what I am doing (and indeed what your code is doing) can be considered "safe" from a memory-leak point of view - as I mentioned, my code works 100%